# Alias not updating Python Binary

Tags: bash, shell, unix, alias

Below is some necessary context for understanding my questions (my shell is `/bin/bash` by the way):

```
~
$ alias
alias dotfiles='/usr/bin/git --git-dir=$HOME/.dotfiles --work-tree=$HOME'
alias ll='ls -al'
alias pip='pip3'
alias python='/usr/local/bin/python3'
~
$ which python
/usr/bin/python
~
$ which python3
/usr/local/bin/python3
~
$ python3 --version
Python 3.9.5
~
$ python --version
Python 3.9.5
~
$ ll /usr/bin/python*
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel     75 Feb  1  2020 /usr/bin/python -> ../../System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python2.7
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel     82 Feb  1  2020 /usr/bin/python-config -> ../../System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python2.7-config
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel     75 Feb  1  2020 /usr/bin/python2 -> ../../System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python2.7
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel     75 Feb  1  2020 /usr/bin/python2.7 -> ../../System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python2.7
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel     82 Feb  1  2020 /usr/bin/python2.7-config -> ../../System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python2.7-config
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  31488 Oct 30  2020 /usr/bin/python3
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel     76 Feb  1  2020 /usr/bin/pythonw -> ../../System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/pythonw2.7
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel     76 Feb  1  2020 /usr/bin/pythonw2.7 -> ../../System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/pythonw2.7
~
$ ll /usr/local/bin/python*
lrwxr-xr-x  1 marshallmcquillen  admin  38 May 18 06:14 /usr/local/bin/python3 -> ../Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.5/bin/python3
lrwxr-xr-x  1 marshallmcquillen  admin  45 May 18 06:14 /usr/local/bin/python3-config -> ../Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.5/bin/python3-config
lrwxr-xr-x  1 marshallmcquillen  admin  40 May 18 06:14 /usr/local/bin/python3.9 -> ../Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.5/bin/python3.9
lrwxr-xr-x  1 marshallmcquillen  admin  47 May 18 06:14 /usr/local/bin/python3.9-config -> ../Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.5/bin/python3.9-config
```

**My Questions:**

1. Why is my alias for python not working? (I've also tried just having `alias python=python3` in my `~/.bash_profile` and it still doesn't point to the correct binary)
2. Why does the `python` link point to (what appears to be) a python2.7 binary, but the version shows 3.9.5?
3. Is the answer to #1 or #2 somehow related to [the difference between `brew install` and `pip3 install`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32530506/is-there-a-difference-between-brew-install-and-pip-install)?

Comment: when you run program then system first get path from `alias`  which points to `python3`. When you use `which` then it doesn't check aliases but only real files - probably set with `update-alternatives`

Comment: It _is_ working for all we can see.  When you run `python --version` it outputs what we expect.  The real question here is probably ["why is `which` the wrong tool?"](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/85249/why-not-use-which-what-to-use-then)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the wrong command:

```
which P
```

by definition searches for an executable named `P` in the PATH.

To see how a command is actually interpreted by bash, you could do a

```
type P
```

in your case:

```
type python
```

BTW, it can become confusing to give an alias the same name as an executable in your PATH. Since the purpose of an alias is to simplify typing on the command line, I suggest that you name your alias to Python something short, like `py`.